# Error in react when i add express in router folder

Tags: reactjs, express, backend, express-router

When i add `const express = require('express')` in my routes/index.js i get this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI1FY.png)

Comment: You cannot include nodejs modules such as express from within a React application made with CRA. Add those lines to a seperate js file outside of your react project's "src" folder, and run it with node.

Comment: a friend has her in src and her react app runs